# Method not working unless page refreshed Nuxt / Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a link in **index.vue** and when I click the link it will be redirected to another page called **/recommendations/search**

```
<template>
  <div>
     <b-button class="btn-sm" @click="addRecommendation" variant="outline-primary">Add Recommendation</b-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script> 
  export default {
    addRecommendation() {
      this.$router.push(`/recommendations/search?uuid=${this.uuid}`)
    }
  }
</script>
```

and in my **recommendations/search** page I have a method called **submit**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form @submit="search">
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <b-form-input v-model="searchTerm" size="lg" type="text" placeholder="Search POI..." autocomplete="off"></b-form-input>
        </b-col>
        <b-col>
          <b-button class="btn-lg" @click="search" variant="outline-primary">Search</b-button>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-form>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios';
  export default { 
   data() {
      return {
        searchTerm: '', 
      }
   },
   methods: {
      search(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        // I'm calling an api here using axios
      }
   } 
</script>
```

I'm getting an **400 Bad Request** when i click the submit but when I refreshed the page I can call the API.

Comment: did you try to remove `@submit="search"` and keep only `@click="search"`?

Comment: This is off-topic but you don't need to do `event.preventDefault()`. You can just use the `.prevent` modifier on your listener like this `@click.prevent`.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yup i tried to do it. when I go to the search page I cannot trigger the method I need to refresh again. I'm getting error from axios 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: It seems like there happens something different server side than client side. Could you share your axios code and could you describe also for what you use the uuid for and how it gets created?